# tor relay - how to display remaining bandwith quota?

Tags: proxy, bandwidth, tor, debian-squeeze, relay

I have a noobish question.

I am experimenting with tor and would like to offer a relay service without exit node.

My relay goes into hibernation surprisingly fast (inspite of setting AccountingMax and AccountingStart, RelayBandwidthRate...etc).

For this reason I would like to know if there is some tor command / option that will display the remaining or already used quota for the given period).

I tried to google the solution but without luck... I can't believe the tor daemon cannot display this information.

Thank you very much

(PS I am using Debian Squeeze with Tor v0.2.2.39 installed via apt-get directly from the repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use control port to manage logs:

edint /etc/tor/torrc, and uncomment line ControlPort 9051

Then open telnet on this control port,

```
telnet localhost 9051
AUTHENTICATE     
setevents STATUS_SERVER
QUIT
```

For a complete listing of event types use the following command:

```
getinfo events/names
```